# How I can access FTP server based on different network

Tags: macos, networking, ftp

I have set up a FTP server with Apache FTP server on local machine, this machine can access internet but its IP address cannot be accessed externally.

I also have another machine in a different city - it can access the internet but it is same in that its IP address cannot be accessed externally. The two computers are not on the same network so they are unable ping each other.

How I can use FTP client from another machine to access the FTP server, I know it should be impossible but do you guys have any workarounds (whatever code change or other approaches)

I am in the US - do you guys have idea how I can make my home IP publicly accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is very possible if you control the firewall that the server is behind.  this is standard network configuration, and you can find hundreds of tutorials online, but the most important bit of information is the *firewall*, not the ftp server.  you configure port forwarding on your firewall to forward incoming ftp requests to your internal ftp server.  also, you will want to use "passive" ftp from the client because the client is also behind a firewall.

Comment: but the ip address are ping-able, they are not able to access each others, does still can be connected? do you any tutorials to share to me?

Comment: @JammyC.c - [google "setup ftp server on home computer"](http://www.google.com/search?q=setup+ftp+server+on+home+computer)